Why are there two different q-learning formulas?
I found the following q-learning formula:

in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4C133ilFm3Q&t=521s
I'm now a bit confused, since I thought, that the following one is the correct one:

Could somebody explain me which one is the correct one?

Can you please replace the screenshots with actual formulas written in mathjax? You could just adapt the formulas written in the answer below.

The first equation (the one from the video) looks very wrong, for a few different reasons:

It doesn't involve state-action values $Q(s, a)$, but only something that looks like "state values" $Q(s)$. Q-learning is about state-action values, so there should be both a state and an action as "input" of the $Q$ function.
It is not clear what the $\max$ operator is maximising over.
There should be an $s'$ rather than $s$ for the first $Q(\cdot$) inside the $\max$.
A part of the equation on the right-hand side is simply missing, it ends very abruptly and is incomplete.


The update rule that you think is correct, is indeed correct. However, it can also be rewritten (will be mathematically equivalent) in a form that is more similar to the first one, albeit with all of the mistakes that I pointed out above fixed. I'll start with the equation that you already recognised as being correct, and in a few small steps re-write it in a different form:
\begin{align*}
Q(s, a) &\gets Q(s, a) + \alpha \left( R(s, a) + \gamma \max_{a'} Q(s', a') - Q(s, a) \right) \\
%
Q(s, a) &\gets Q(s, a) + \alpha \left( R(s, a) + \gamma \max_{a'} Q(s', a') \right) - \alpha Q(s, a) \\
%
Q(s, a) &\gets Q(s, a) - \alpha Q(s, a) + \alpha \left( R(s, a) + \gamma \max_{a'} Q(s', a') \right) \\
%
Q(s, a) &\gets \left( 1 - \alpha \right) Q(s, a) + \alpha \left( R(s, a) + \gamma \max_{a'} Q(s', a') \right)
\end{align*}
